# Matplotlib support failed in Pycharm on Windows

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, pycharm

I have a problem with matplotlib in Pycharm.my code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
T = np.linspace(10,100,10)
es = 611*np.exp(17.27*T/(237.3+T))
plt.plot(T,es)
plt.xlabel('T (degree Celcius)')
plt.ylabel('es (pa)')
plt.show()
```

and after i ran this code,Pycharm showed this error:
[enter link description here](http://uupload.ir/files/5pp6_capture3.png)

what should i do to solve it??

Comment: Need more details - were packages installed at the system level or within virtualenv or anaconda? If I had to guess, it's likely an error because Pycharm isn't finding the package because it's not detecting the environment (assuming you installed the packages?)

Comment: Hello dear @IanQuah ! i use anaconda .my other packages were install and work very well . but just matplotlib does not work and when i want to use it, it showes error that you saw. i installed all my packages in Pycharm: settings >> my project interpreter and install all of them separatly. i test it with virtualenv and it workes correct,but what should i do when i want to use anaconda??